# What's the shape and place of the tip vortex in a propeller, depending on propeller sense of turning?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, vortex

If the propeller vortex is placed and has changing features depending on the propeller sense of turning, both in traction and pusher configuration, knowing about this may have an interest for the design of multi-propeller airplanes.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29564/62) might help

Answer (score 2):

I too am unsure exactly what your question is but propeller blades shed vortices at the tips just like wings and rotor blades. This vortices and their paths can be seen when the weather conditions are right as in this photograph. (I don't own this image)

[image]

You can find many more of these types of images with a quick google search. The vortices roughly follow the advance ratio of the propeller at the moment they form. There would be little difference to the formation of vortices for push or pull configuration.